# How to use UIElement[] CreateLabels method in NumericLabelProviderBase class to insert label or text in a point inside plotter

Tags: wpf, charts, wpf-controls, uielement, dynamic-data-display

I'm tring to override CreateLabels  to insert labels or text in specific points in plotter chart but I need a help in:
1.  what does the parameter (`ITicksInfo<double> ticksInfo`) mean and what should I send to it
2. how to use the return value to add labels to already defined Axis like _stringaxis.LabelProvider

or if there is simpler way to add text in a point please tell,

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the easiest way to add a nice label inside the chart.

```
CenteredTextMarker label = new CenteredTextMarker();
        label.Text = text;
//just dawing a line with one dot tall in the same position you want the label to be 

plotter.AddLineGraph(compositeDataSource1, 
                                 dptLine,
                                 label,
                                 new PenDescription(ComponentName));
```

and I'm Hiding the legend and build a customized one my self by doing

```
plotter.LegendVisible = false;
```